# Constrain keys that are part of looked-up type

Tags: typescript, types, algebraic-data-types, complex-data-types

I need to create a constraint that limits keys of `TP1` listed by the `keyof` keyword to properties that are of a specific type. When I use the `builder.setMetadata` method, the first parameter should not accept string "configure" as a valid value (it should accept `foo` and other keys that are typed as `Foo<something>`). I've tried to come up with a solution by myself, but I'm a bit lost and have been doing it for more than three hours now. Following is the working code:

```
interface Foo<T> {};

class Test { prop: string; }

class Builder<T> {
    public setMetadata<TP1 extends keyof this, TP2 extends keyof this[TP1]>(prop: TP1, propOfProp: TP2) {
        // ...
    }
}

class Bar {
    foo: Foo<Test>;

    configure(builder: Builder<Bar>) {
        builder.setMetadata("", ""); // only "foo" should be accepted value in the first argument, "configure" shouldn't be in the list
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
class Builder<T> {
  public setMetadata<TP1 extends keyof T, TP2 extends T[TP1]>(prop: TP1, propOfProp: TP2) {
    // ...
  }
}

class BarData {
  foo: Foo<Test>;
}

class Bar extends BarData {
  configure(builder: Builder<BarData>) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I made changes in a few places:

- use `T` instead of `this` in setMetadata's type
- don't use `keyof` in setMetadata's second param type
- move foo into a separate class

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Using inheritance unfortunately isn't an option - the `configure` method is going to be defined in a class that's going to be a parent to the class that holds the foo property. It's part of a client-facing API and I'd like to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Are you actually intending `Foo<T>` to be empty, hoping to use it just for constraining type params in setMetadata? That won't work because of the structural-typing nature of TypeScript. An empty interface will accept anything. You would have to box the fields in a class instance or a container object with a special marker field to be able to do this. Or maybe you could do something with decorators (I haven't used them so can't comment).

Comment: You're right. I solved it in a different way (functions), see my own answer. Decorators wouldn't solve the issue, unfortunately. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself using a function:

```
function createInstance<T extends Function & { [P in keyof TSchema]: Foo<any> }>(schema: T, configure: (builder: Builder<T["prototype"]>) => void): any {
    // ...
}
```